# Different animation when the size changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, slick.js

I need the the animation to change based on the screen size.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 900) {
    $(".slider").slick({
      centerMode: true,
      slidesToShow: 1,
    });
  } else {
    $(".slider").slick({
      centerMode: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
    });
  }
});
```

The above code only works when I reload the page. I want it to change as the screen size changes without the need of reloading. Can you help me?

Comment: so add resize event handler, hopefully slick can handle the change

Comment: [resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event)

Comment: Use [media queries programmatically via `MediaQueryList.addListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener).